# How to merge the two columns from two dataframe into one column of a new dataframe (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, nan

I want to merge the values of two different columns of pandas dataframe into one column of new dataframe.

```
pandas df1 =         

        hapX
  pos   0.0
1 721   0.2
2 735   0.5
3 739   1.0


pandas df2 =       

        hapY
  pos   0.1
1 721   0.0
2 735   0.6
3 739   1.5
```

I want to generate a new dataframe like:

```
  df_joined['hapX|Y'] = df1.astype(str).add('|').add(df2.astype(str))
```

with **expected output**:

```
        hapX|Y
  pos   0.0|0.1
1 721   0.2|0.0
2 735   0.5|0.6
3 739   1.0|1.5
```

But, this is outputting bunch of `NaN`

```
        hapX    hapY
  pos   NaN      NaN
1 721   NaN      NaN
2 735   NaN      NaN
3 739   NaN      NaN
```

Is the problem with value being float (i don't think so). What is the problem with my approach?

**Also, is there a way to automate the process if columns values are like `hapX1 hapX1 hapX3` in one dataframe with `hapY1 hapY2 hapY3` in another dataframe?**

Thanks,

Comment: `df1.hapX.astype(str) + '|'  + df2.pahY.astype(str)` will simply give you a new column that you can add to a data frame.

Comment: actually that is not working and throwing an `attribute error`

Comment: Are the indexes all the same?

Comment: yes the `pos` indexes are the same. But, the `column` indexes are different as you can see in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the two dataframes and then concat the hapX and hapY. 
Say your first column name is no.

```
df_joined = df1.merge(df2, on = 'no')
df_joined['hapX|Y'] = (df_joined['hapX'].astype(str))+'|'+(df_joined['hapY'].astype(str))
df_joined.drop(['hapX', 'hapY'], axis = 1)
```

This gives you

```
    no  hapX|Y
0   pos 0.0|0.1
1   721 0.2|0.0
2   735 0.5|0.6
3   739 1.0|1.5
```

Comment: what is `on='no'`. I am getting `KeyError: 'no'`

Comment: @everestial007 seriously? It is the second sentence, **Say your first column name is no**

Comment: I created the df using df1 = pd.DataFrame({'no': ['pos', 721, 735, 739], 'hapX': [0.0, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0]}) as I was not able to reproduce your df using read_clipboard(). You can name the column using df.columns

Answer (score 1):

Just to add onto the previous answer, for the general case of N DataFrames,

Suppose you have a number of DataFrames as follows:

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame({'hapY'+str(j): [random.random() for i in range(10)]}) for j in range(5)]
```

such that

```
>>> dfs[0]
      hapY0
0  0.175683
1  0.353729
2  0.949848
3  0.346088
4  0.435292
5  0.837879
6  0.277274
7  0.623121
8  0.325119
9  0.709252
```

Then,

```
>>> map( lambda m: '|'.join(m) , zip(*[ dfs[j]['hapY'+str(j)].astype(str)  for j in range(5)]))
['0.0845464936138|0.193336164837|0.551717121013|0.113566029656|0.479590342798',
 '0.275851474238|0.694161791339|0.151607726092|0.615367668451|0.498997567849',
 '0.116891472119|0.258406028668|0.315137581816|0.819992354178|0.864412473301',
 '0.729581942312|0.614902776003|0.443986436146|0.227782256619|0.0149481683863',
 '0.745583477173|0.441456815889|0.428691631831|0.307480112319|0.136790112739',
 '0.981337451224|0.0117895017035|0.415140979617|0.650957722911|0.968082350568',
 '0.725618728314|0.0546057041356|0.715910454674|0.0828229441557|0.220878025678',
 '0.704047455894|0.303403129266|0.0499082759635|0.49727194707|0.251623048104',
 '0.453595354131|0.146042134766|0.346665276655|0.911092176243|0.291405609407',
 '0.140523603089|0.117930249858|0.902071673051|0.0804933425857|0.876006332635']
```

which you can later put into a DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simpliest is rename columns by `dict` which can be created by `dict comprehension`, last [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
print (df1) 
     hapX1  hapX2  hapX3  hapX4
pos                            
23     1.0    0.0    1.0    1.0
24     1.0    1.0    1.5    1.0
28     1.0    0.0    0.5    0.0

print (df2)
     hapY1  hapY2  hapY3  hapY4
pos                            
23     0.0    1.0    0.5    0.0
24     1.0    1.0    1.5    1.0
28     0.0    1.0    1.0    1.0

d = {'hapY' + str(x):'hapX' + str(x) for x in range(1,5)}
print (d)
{'hapY1': 'hapX1', 'hapY3': 'hapX3', 'hapY2': 'hapX2', 'hapY4': 'hapX4'}

df_joined = df1.astype(str).add('|').add(df2.rename(columns=d).astype(str)).add_suffix('|Y')
print (df_joined) 

     hapX1|Y  hapX2|Y  hapX3|Y  hapX4|Y
pos                                    
23   1.0|0.0  0.0|1.0  1.0|0.5  1.0|0.0
24   1.0|1.0  1.0|1.0  1.5|1.5  1.0|1.0
28   1.0|0.0  0.0|1.0  0.5|1.0  0.0|1.0
```